# JavaFX graphics "blurred" or anti-aliased? (No effects used)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating some some shapes and everything seems to be blurred, like anti-aliased despite no effects applied.

For example, a white line drawn on a black backgroud with 1 pixel width, is rendered grey! Changing the width to 2px results in white, but not well-defined.

When searching, the method `setSmooth(false)` on shapes returned, but calling it makes no difference.

What should I change or disable on `Stage` or `Scene`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) documentation:

> Most nodes tend to have only integer translations applied to them and
>   quite often they are defined using integer coordinates as well. For
>   this common case, fills of shapes with straight line edges tend to be
>   crisp since they line up with the cracks between pixels that fall on
>   integer device coordinates and thus tend to naturally cover entire
>   pixels.
>
> On the other hand, stroking those same shapes can often lead to fuzzy
>   outlines because the default stroking attributes specify both that the
>   default stroke width is 1.0 coordinates which often maps to exactly 1
>   device pixel and also that the stroke should straddle the border of
>   the shape, falling half on either side of the border. Since the
>   borders in many common shapes tend to fall directly on integer
>   coordinates and those integer coordinates often map precisely to
>   integer device locations, the borders tend to result in 50% coverage
>   over the pixel rows and columns on either side of the border of the
>   shape rather than 100% coverage on one or the other. Thus, fills may
>   typically be crisp, but strokes are often fuzzy.
>
> Two common solutions to avoid these fuzzy outlines are to use wider
>   strokes that cover more pixels completely - typically a stroke width
>   of 2.0 will achieve this if there are no scale transforms in effect -
>   or to specify either the StrokeType.INSIDE or StrokeType.OUTSIDE
>   stroke styles - which will bias the default single unit stroke onto
>   one of the full pixel rows or columns just inside or outside the
>   border of the shape.

And see also the documentation of [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> At the device pixel level, integer coordinates map onto the corners
>   and cracks between the pixels and the centers of the pixels appear at
>   the midpoints between integer pixel locations. Because all coordinate
>   values are specified with floating point numbers, coordinates can
>   precisely point to these corners (when the floating point values have
>   exact integer values) or to any location on the pixel. For example, a
>   coordinate of (0.5, 0.5) would point to the center of the upper left
>   pixel on the Stage. Similarly, a rectangle at (0, 0) with dimensions
>   of 10 by 10 would span from the upper left corner of the upper left
>   pixel on the Stage to the lower right corner of the 10th pixel on the
>   10th scanline. The pixel center of the last pixel inside that
>   rectangle would be at the coordinates (9.5, 9.5).

So your options for clean lines when you have an odd stroke width are:

1. Use a StrokeType.INSIDE or StrokeType.OUTSIDE stroke style.
2. Offset the co-ordinates of shapes by 0.5 of a pixel so that the strokes line up on the lines rather than the cracks between lines.
3. Just use the next even number up as the stroke width, e.g. 1 => 2, 3 => 4, etc.

As to why `setSmooth(false)` does not work, I don't know exactly, my guess is that the antialiasing it refers to is independent of the antialiasing styles performed when strokes are centered on the cracks between pixels, but I would not know why that would be.

Comment: I read everything you paste, (and I´m a little ashamed now for googled a lot but never remember to look at javafoc =\), and tested all the solutions u pruposed!
1 - In a line with 1px width, if I set INSIDE, the line disappears! With a OUTSIDE, it take a 2px width total. Not really functional for  my needs..
2 - this had the perfectly results... I´m going with thas...
3 - this works as well, that was the solution I found before, but just works for even numbers...

Anyway, really thanks for your reply, it´s solved my problem at all. And teach me a leason: before ask, read the javadoc! lol...

Comment: Don't worry, it's a reasonable question and the behavior, especially in relation to `setSmooth`, is a bit subtle and not particularly intuitive.

Comment: I edit my comment because I press Enter to try to break the line and it confirmed the just the first part... Thanks again!