# Javafx path stroke width Lineto

Tags: path, width, javafx, opacity, stroke

I just did some tests with Path of JavaFX, and I observed a bug when I work with the LineTo :

```
Path border = GraphUtil.buildBorder(w, h, ARC_BORDER);
border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
border.setStrokeWidth(0.3);
border.setOpacity(0.8);
```

With my utility method :

```
public class GraphUtil {

    public static Path buildBorder(double w, double h, double arcBorder) {
        //FIXME apply arcborder
        Path border = new Path();
        MoveTo mTo = new MoveTo();
        mTo.setX(0);
        mTo.setY(0);
        LineTo lTop = new LineTo();
        lTop.setX(w);
        lTop.setY(0);
        LineTo lRight = new LineTo();
        lRight.setX(w);
        lRight.setY(h);
        LineTo lBottom = new LineTo();
        lBottom.setX(0);
        lBottom.setY(h);
        LineTo lLeft = new LineTo();
        lLeft.setX(0);
        lLeft.setY(0);
        border.getElements().addAll(mTo, lTop, lRight, lBottom, lLeft);

        return border;
    }
}
```

When I do that, it's ok. But when I want the strokewidth to be smaller (0.2 or 0.1), the left border is invisible, the other ones are visible.. Does someone know why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe same reason as this?

So your options for clean lines when you have an odd stroke width are:

Use a StrokeType.INSIDE or StrokeType.OUTSIDE stroke style.
Offset the co-ordinates of shapes by 0.5 of a pixel so that the strokes line up on the lines rather than the cracks between lines.
Just use the next even number up as the stroke width, e.g. 1 => 2, 3 => 4, etc.

[JavaFX graphics "blurred" or anti-aliased? (No effects used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779693/javafx-graphics-blurred-or-anti-aliased-no-effects-used)